# Make ReSharper respect your preference for code order

Tags: c#, coding-style, resharper

Related to my other question: [What's the best way to layout a C# class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603758/whats-the-best-way-to-layout-a-c-class)

Is there a way in ReSharper to define the order you want your members to be in, so that ReSharper will maintain it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603758/whats-the-best-way-to-layout-a-c-class/603787#603787):

Check under **Type Members Layout** in **Options** (under the **C#** node). It's not simple, but it is possible to change the layout order.

Answer (score 0):

Check [File and Type Layout](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/File_and_Type_Layout.html) in Resharper's help documentation -

> ReSharper can reorder types and type members in C# files according to different patterns. Patterns can describe a lot of conditions and constraints that are evaluated when reordering items in a file and/or wrapping them with specified regions.

The page describes how those patterns work, how to configure them (two options here -  use a visual editor or edit the XAML source) and finally, how to apply your settings.