# C# organizing my code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resharper, code-formatting, code-organization

does any tool (VS extension, or maybe Resharper supports this...) exist
which can orginize code in my class in some specified  way? Like this :

```
public static fields/properties
private static fields/properties

public fields/properties
private fields/properties

constructors

public static methods
private static methods

public methods
private methods
```

etc

(and all are sorted alphabetically)

It would be so nice...

I like to have my code very organized, but sometimes I do not follow my own rules and than reorganizing everything by hands may be a little bit problematic )

Comment: Also see [make-resharper-respect-your-preference-for-code-order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603805/make-resharper-respect-your-preference-for-code-order?lq=1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, ReSharper can do it. You can even customize the way it organizes items... take a look at this blog post by Hadi Hariri http://hadihariri.com/2011/01/04/in-depth-look-at-customizing-type-layout-with-resharper/

Comment: Thank's for that amazing post!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, resharper has such a feature (and many other equally marvelous ones).

Answer (score 3):

Telerik's [JustCode](http://www.telerik.com/products/justcode.aspx) has this feature as well. Code ordering rules are easily customizable through the Options dialog - No XML.
[image: JustCode - Reordering]

Comment: Nice! I'll try it, but I trust resharper a little bit more)