# Is there any good reason why the #region and #endregion does not work in F#

Tags: f#, region

This is very useful in organizing and browsing the code. Why is it not implemented? And if it would prevent some constructs why not have something similar for F#?

Comment: Why would code folding prevent other features of a language from being possible? That makes no sense.

Comment: Code folding is not a language feature - but is more or less a editing presentation directive. Its presense or lack thereof does not change the behaviour or execution of said program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a feature that the F# team would love to add, but it is more of a "nice to have" sort of feature and isn't necessary to ship for v1 of the product release. We'll see more of these types of features make their way into F# in a future version of release of Visual Studio. For Visual Studio 2010, it's been a great deal of work to get F# to product quality.

Comment: I can certainly understand that.

Answer (score 6):

I agree code folding is nice and we need annotations in the code, but
I'd like something more generic than region/endregion; I'd like a
generic way to give information to IDE, a generic way that's not
checked by the compiler (so that IDEs can implement features, without
requiring a change in the compiler).

That being said, code folding is not always a good thing. As Jeff Atwood points out in [his blog post](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-problem-with-code-folding/) about code folding and some of it's pitfalls. Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916/how-do-you-feel-about-code-folding/7767#7767) has some valid points.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine F# is not yet mature enough to have all of the features of C# and VB.NET. I'm sure that if it is around for a bit longer the non-critical features such as code folding will follow.